# Animation is called twice

Tags: android, listview

I have a listView and I want to remove an item from it.

After user slides from right to left animation of item going away begins. Then, this item should be removed.

My code:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.note,null);
        }
        final RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView9);
        textView.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        Button button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button10);
        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    x = event.getX();
                }
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    if (Math.abs(event.getX() - x) > (float)150) {
                        Log.e("Point_1", "Begin animate");
                        arrayList.remove(position);
                        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(relativeLayout, "x", 0 - relativeLayout.getWidth());
                        objectAnimator.setDuration(600);
                        objectAnimator.start();
                        Log.e("Point_1", "Start removing");

                        ListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
}
```

When I run my app almost everything goes fine. Items are removed after sliding. Animation of removing view is fine too. But! Somehow item that was right under my removing view starts an animation too and after it(animation) it is not removed from listView. What is wrong?

Before removing:

[image]

And after(3 items - 2 texts):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If someone will ever have issue like this.

Create a new directory "anim" in res folder of your project. Then create there animation that you wanted. In your class(-es) write these

```
final Animation animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim."name of animation that you've already created");
animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            //Do whatever you've wanted to do. In my case I remove item from listView.

                arrayList.remove(position);
                ListViewAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
```